# Cutting laminate countertop with minimal waste

Tags: kitchen-counters

I have a 6-foot long "slab" of laminate kitchen countertop that I need to cut in half. Each half will be installed on top of a 36-inch long base cabinet.

At least, that is my tentative plan. I am concerned that when I cut the countertop in half, I'll lose an eighth of an inch or so to the saw blade, I'll therefore end up with two pieces of countertop that are just short of 36 inches long, and they won't quite fully cover the cabinets.

Is that something I should be concerned about? Is there a way to minimize the loss from the saw blade (would cutting really slowly help, for example) or to squeeze any length out of the cabinets so that the counter top will fit them cleanly? Or any kind of trim that people use in this situation to hide the imperfection if the countertop is a little too short for the cabinet?

Comment: Countertops almost always hang over the edge of the cabinet - you want it to be totally flush to the side?

Comment: the edge trim should basically cancel out the saw blade width, if not leave it slightly longer in total than before the cut.

Comment: Thin kerf blades are more like a 16th, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

They do make edging strip (glues on, at least that's the one I used) to close the open sides and they also do aluminum edging strip or chromed ones.

If I find a link...

Oh, and measure twice and cut once : definitely don't want to go wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Score the face with a razor knife a few times, using a straight edge as a guide clamped down to the work surface.

Then flip upside down and cut half the thickness of the laminate opposite your score line with a circular saw and a straight edge as a guide clamped down to the work surface.

Bend the laminate up until it snaps on the score line.

Glue laminate sides in first, trim with router with flush cut bit. Glue laminate top on next, and trim with router again with flush cut bit.

If your laminate is too short, leave the gap at the wall and cut it off when you scribe it to the wall.

If your laminate is still too short, buy another sheet and do it right.

Comment: I think the OP has a kitchen worktop which has a laminate on the surface, and core of HDF or chipboard.  You seem to be discussing how to cut a single sheet of laminate that has not been glued to a core yet.